# I hope that someone would or could help me out

Tags: modal-verbs

> Ella had hoped that her husband would grow into a family-oriented man.

or

> Ella had hoped that her husband could grow into a family-oriented man.

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are correct, English sentences. However, the best option depends on the meaning you are trying to convey (what specifically Ella hoped for).

> **Could:** the past tense of can, a verb used to denote *ability*. In this sense, could refers to some ability that someone had in the past.
>
> **Would:** the past tense of *will*, which denotes both ability and certainty.

The above is from https://writingexplained.org/could-vs-would-difference.

1. Ella had hoped that her husband **would** grow into a family-oriented man.

Explanation: Ella wanted her husband to actually grow into a family-oriented man. She didn't just want him to have the ability to do so. She wants him to exercise that ability and actually become a family-oriented man.

2. Ella had hoped that her husband **could** grow into a family-oriented man.

Explanation: Ella hoped that her husband had the ability to grow into a family-oriented man. This sentence does not specify whether or not she wanted him to actually *become* that family-oriented man; his ability to do so is all she explicitly hopes for.